# Why does inner joining (a) 2 functions or (b) 2 temp tables with results of same functions have such a great performance difference?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

So I see this quite often in SQL Server 2012 and have also seen this SQL Server 2008 R2. Suppose I have a query:

```
  Select *
  From function1(@param1, @param2) f1
       INNER JOIN function2(@param1, @param2) f2 ON
          f1.key = f2.key
```

This will take about 5 minutes to run because I think (and maybe I'm dead wrong but it looks like) it evaluates function2 again when it gets a new row from function1. Now if I rewrite it as:

```
 Select *
 Into #f1
 From function1(@param1, @param2)

 Select *
 Into #f2
 From function2(@param1, @param2)

 Select *
 From #f1 f1
     INNER JOIN #f2 f2 on
       f1.key = f2.key
```

This will take 3 seconds to run. I don't understand why the optimizer decides to evaluate these scenarios differently. Is there a hint I can use so I don't have to do this workaround? Why is it happening?

Comment: Examine the actual execution plan to see what is going on. You can post it here (use pastebin.com if XML is too large) and we could confirm whether your first variant indeed calls the function for each row. (I don't think it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

First, if you were talking about a scalar UDF, or using `CROSS APPLY` / `OUTER APPLY`, then yes, it would run those for each row.

However, in the case of joining two TVFs, you need to consider the following:

- Inline TVFs are really just Views that can accept parameters. Because of this, their definition, just like what happens with Views, gets inserted into the query that is using the TVF. This allows the end-result query to be optimizable, and which is why they perform so much better than Multi-statement TVFs. These might JOIN ok in the way that you are using them.
- Multi-statement TVFs:

  - cannot be optimized. They appear to the Query Optimizer as always returning a set number of rows (1000, I believe). This set number of rows can really throw off the execution plan if it is much higher or lower than what really gets returned.
  - have no means of maintaining statistics on their fields. On the other hand, when you join on columns of temporary tables, SQL Server will generate statistics for those columns and use that info to come up with a more accurate execution plan.

What can you do? Well, I suspect based on the 5 minutes vs 3 seconds difference that your TVFs are Multi-statement instead of Inline. If at all possible, convert them to be Inline TVFs (you will be very glad that you did).

Outside of that, if you have a solution that works in 3 seconds compared to 5 minutes for the alternative, is there really a problem? You could also create the two temporary tables via `CREATE TABLE` rather than `SELECT INTO`, which might help a tiny bit.

Comment: Is there a HINT that I can give the optimizer so I can keep this inline (instead of using my workaround to turn this into a multi-statement TVF)?

Comment: @Denis Not that I am aware of. And you never mentioned putting this code into a TVF. If that is the case, then you can't use temp tables and will have to use table variables. And in that case, you will once again have performance issues since table variables also do not keep statistics on their columns. They also only appear to have 1 row, but can overcome that by using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, though that is a performance hit itself, but is something better than not using it, but not sure if you can do that in a TVF.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly compare the use of temporary tables to a function call.  When you create the temporary table and then run a query, the compiler knows something important about the tables -- how big they are.  This information is then used for execution.

I don't think the functions are called multiple times, even in the first case.

So, I suspect that the issue is the size of the tables and the join algorithm that is then used.  In SQL Server 2014, you might try a memory optimized table.

You could also try CTEs, although I don't think that will help (because the CTEs are evaluated *after* compilation):

```
with f1 as (
      Select *
      From function1(@param1, @param2)
     ),
     f2 as (
      Select *
      From function2(@param1, @param2)
     )
Select *
From f1 INNER JOIN
     f2
     on f1.key = f2.key;
```

Another option is to use a compiler option to use a hash or merge join.

Comment: In SQL Server CTEs are not materialized (as opposed to Postgres, for example). They behave like views, i.e. they are inlined. Your query with CTE would produce exactly the same execution plan as original query in the question without CTE.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . Correct.  That is exactly why I don't think it will help the query (although perhaps something might trigger the optimizer to behave differently, somehow).